# Image Classification in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a database of images and an excel sheet of the Category for each image. How do I merge the two to use this for my training process?
ex: In the excel sheet: Image name and Category are given

Comment: Hi Sushi, did you try anything yet? Can you provide more information so we can help? How is your images database ? "merging the two" what do you exactly want? You want to apply categories to your images? Please provide some code and more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is, your images are in one dataset, and their corresponding labels are in an Excel file, right? And you are wondering how to combine them and feed into the model. Well, if the question is this, you can load the image as x_train/x_test/x_val, and judge categories as y_train/y_test/y_val. Then feed them into the model as input. (Of course you need to map them by image_name)

Or a more intuitive way is, you can just use read_csv file from pandas to load excel as dataframe, as well as get all the images name as another dataframe. Next, merge two dataframe into one, taking the image name as keys. Then the following process are the same in every model training. Hope this can help.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem I was facing. It worked! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

How many images do you have? If not too much, you can load all of them to memory. Hold a list for the images and a list for the labels.

You can do that by iterating over your excel sheet, for each row, insert a label to the labels list, and load the corresponding image to the images list.

Then you can provide these two lists to Keras's model.fit

Hope that helps.